# No such module "PackageDescription" Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to use [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=calendar%20cocoapod&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS751US751&oq=calendar%20cocoapod&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3302j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) cocoapod for calendar functionality, but I am running into an error.  I properly installed the cocoapod, but the tutorial also had me drag and drop some files into my xcode project.  Among those files is Package.Swift.  At the top, it has me import PackageDescription and I am getting this error.[image: This Error].  If I get rid of this file I get many more errors throughout the project.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to:
1) delete these entered lines with import, etc.
2) reopen the Xcode
3) press Cmd + B
4) write import PackageDescription again

It helped me many times.